# Segmentation fault on file write

Tags: c, printf

When I am trying to print to a file it gives a segmentation fault. How can I print date and time to file?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    time_t mytime;

    mytime=time(NULL);
    fp=("sys.txt","w+");

    fprintf(fp,"%s",ctime(&mytime));
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fp = fopen("sys.txt", "w+");`

Comment: `fp=("sys.txt","w+");` Is this a cut and paste problem or your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to (a) call `fopen()` and (b) pay attention to your compiler's warnings.  If you didn't get compiler warnings, turn them on or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault usually occurs when your program tries to access memory that it doesn't own or have access permission to.

This problem occurs in your program because you have incorrectly tried to open a file. You have to use the `fopen()` call to open a file:

`FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);`

In its present state, the program tries to write a string to a file described by a file descriptor containing some random value. That is, it tries to write to a random file that might not exist and that it definitely does not have write access to.

If you compiled your code with gcc, you would see this notifying you of a potential problem:

`warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fp=("sys.txt","w+");` with `fp=fopen("sys.txt","w+");`

And read about [File Operations in C](http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-for-file-operations.html)